# Google drive permanent permission

Tags: python, google-drive-api, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on small python script (raspberry pi + Linux) that getting filename, as script argument, and upload it to Google drive.

In order to upload file to Google drive, I'm using this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python

This script is basically working good, but, it's require manual authorization of the request - EACH time. This impossible when developing automated background task.

What I'm want to improve is to accept my application **only once**. From this time, all the file upload tasks will pass without security questions.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to follow server-side auth.  Basically you store a refresh token that you receive the first time the user authorizes you, and you can use that to get new tokens without prompting the user.

See https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server